# Paginator and Routers - the GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm learning laravel and I'm having a problem with one route:

```
Route::post('/sortby/{id}', [GuestBook::class, 'Sort'])->name('sort');
```

Function implementation:

```
public function Sort($val = 0, Request $request)
{
    $type = '';
    foreach ($request->except('_token') as $key => $value) {
        $type = $key;
    }

    $pag_num = 10;
    $data = guest_table::where('is_pub', 1);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'byid':
            $data = $data->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'byidDesc':
            $data = $data->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'byemail':
            $data = $data->orderBy('email', 'asc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'byemailDesc':
            $data = $data->orderBy('email', 'desc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'byusername':
            $data = $data->orderBy('username', 'asc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'byusernameDesc':
            $data = $data->orderBy('username', 'asc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'bydate':
            $data = $data->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        case 'bydateDesc':
            $data = $data->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($pag_num);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return view('posts', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

So, when I process a post request for sorting by certain fields, I get a redirect to http://127.0.0.1/sortby/0.

When I use the paginator I get the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/sortby/0?page=2 and gives me the error **the GET method is not supported for this route**.

I understand that when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/sortby/0?page=2, a get request is sent from me, but I don't know how to solve it(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `post` route on `Route::post('/sortby/{id}', [GuestBook::class, 'Sort'])->name('sort');`. That's why you are receiving this error.

Just change it to:

```
Route::get('/sortby/{id}', [GuestBook::class, 'Sort'])->name('sort');
```

This might throw an error if you are sending the request to  `http://127.0.0.1/sortby/0` as a `post` request, at the first time, you have to change it on the front end as well, and need to send it as a `get` request instead.